# determine Big-O Notation for functions

Tags: c, algorithm, function, big-o

In my course of algorithms we talk about time complexity with Big O Notation. And I am always confused when I try to calculate the Big O. I know for example when a function then it can be O(n) or O(n²). But I don't know the logical background and how to get this solution for each function.

```
int func1(int n){ 
   for (int i=1; i<n; i=i*2) 
   printf("i = %d", i); return i; 
}

int func2(int a, int b) {
   int result=1; 
   while (b>0) {
      result = result*a; 
      b = b-1; 
   }
   return result;
}

void func3(int n) {
   for (int i=0; i<pow(2,n); i++) 
      printf("%d", i);  
}
```

Comment: You tagged this question as Python, but your code looks C-ish?

Comment: This sounds like a question *for your professor or TA*.

Comment: I am sorry was my fault @ChristianDean and thanks for help.

Comment: So many people here are posting some questions which sound like a question for the professor or TA. @juanpa.arrivillaga ;) and nevertheless they get an answer.

Comment: @mrleo the topic is immensely broad, and anyway, there are several existing questions on the topic.

Comment: There is a difference. Calculating complexity is quite a bit of theory, presumably taught by your prof and spanning across a significant part of your course and several tens of textbook pages. SO answer space is limited by few hundreds of lines (and that would be considered too many).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Big O notation is talking about worst case, how long will the function run?

If you have Func2, with b = 1, six instructions run. Assignment, Comparison, Assignment, Assignment, Comparison, Return. When b = 2, 9 instructions are run. We can tell right away that the number of instructions is 3+(3*n). When talking about how long the function will take, we ignore constants both added to our variable, and multiplied by our variable. Because ultimately, when b=1000, that's the overriding factor of how long the function takes to run. And because it increases Linearly with respect to b, the function is said to be O(n) time. (Big O notation always uses 'n' for its variable.)

The first function increases even slower with respect to n, it increases Logarithmically, only adding more computation for each power of 2 that n passes. (More computation when n = 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc)

(Assuming pow(2,n) = n squared; sometimes pow(2,n) = 2 to the power of n)
The third function runs the loop once when n = 1, and 4 times when n = 2, we can see that we're talking about n^2 number of iterations through the loop. This is Exponentially expanding, so it's O(n^2) time.

The way to analyze things for Big O notation is to identify how many instructions run based on n = 1, 2, 3, 4... n Make that a function and identify whether it's Constant (doesn't change based on n), Linear (changes directly proportional to n), Logarithmic (changes based on log(n)), Exponential (changes based on a power of n) or otherwise. (It's been a while, but I remember an n log n type and one that talked about when n is a power that some other exponent is raised to, but memory is hazy on those.)

Comment: I do very much agree that you should directly ask your professor this question, though. All I can do is quote a lesson, but they can walk you through it and find out where you're stumbling.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer I am going to understand it. You wrote _If you have Func1, with n = 1, six instructions run. Assignment, Comparison, Printf, Assignment, Comparison, Return. When n = 2, 9 instructions are run. We can tell right away that the number of instructions is 3+(3*n)._ That means I have to understand the function **line by line** to determine the Big O ?

Comment: Essentially, yes. You can shortcut it a little and look at any repetition in the function. Look for loops (for, while) or for function calls (recursion, if it calls itself...) When starting out, it helps to just list out exactly how many lines will execute, though.

Comment: Func1 is not O(n).  It's O(log(n)).  (Check how i increments)

Comment: Also, it's very likely that Func3 *is* 2^n, not n^2, because that's the standard way of understanding the function, and because that's the C way, which is what mrleo said the programming language is meant to be.  Also, if you only wanted n^2, you'd probably type n*n.

Comment: Now I am really confused.... @ScottMermelstein , how do you get the answer O(log(n))???

Comment: When n = 100, how many I will there be? I= 1, 2,  4, 8, 16, 32, 64. When n = 128 same thing. (You get one more I from n=129 to n=256.) The number of times through the loop is always log (base 2) of n. In big O calculations, we don't care if it's log base 10 or log base 2. Either way, it's O(log(n)).

Comment: Thanks, @ScottMermelstein, I've corrected the answer to give the correct analysis of the first function. I'm leaving the Exponential explanation, though I agree it's probably 2^n, I can't remember the name of that kind of growth.